# Meteor Server Side Redirect Webapp

Tags: javascript, redirect, meteor, routes

Hi guys I am trying to do a redirect in meteor server. So I do it like this

```
WebApp.connectHandlers
  .use(function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req)
    if (req.url === '/') {
      // 307 Temporary Redirect
      console.log(req)
      res.writeHead(307, {
        Location: '/login'
      })
      res.end()
    } else {
      // Let other handlers match
      next()
    }
  })
```

However it redirects to `http://login` instead of `http://localhost:3000/login`

I also tried `Location: 'http://localhost:3000/login'` and

```
res.redirect()
```

But still got the same. What am I doing wrong in here?

Comment: If you are using Iron-Router in your app then you can try using     'Router.go('/login');'

Comment: What happens if you provide a root url as environment variable: https://docs.meteor.com/environment-variables.html#ROOT-URL